# Java: Getting around "The method abc is undefined for the type X" when method is in subclass and parameter is superclass type

Tags: java

I have a superclass, `Entity`, and many subclasses which extend it. In my code, I loop through an ArrayList of entities, and then may call a method defined like this:

```
public void doThing(Entity e) {
    System.out.println("doThing");
    ...
    ...
    e.subclassMethod(); //Assuming at this point the code is only calling this when e has the method
}
```

However, as `subclassMethod` is only defined on a particular subclass, and not in the base `Entity` class, I get the error "The method subclassMethod() is undefined for the type Entity"  (which of course, it is).

What is the correct way of handling this situation, where I need to call a single method, which could pass any number of Entity subclasses as a parameter? Thanks.

Comment: You could use `instanceof` to determine the type. This is not so great. You could declare a method on the `Entity` type and call that. Each subclass would have to implement it, maybe as a no-op.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't have a problem knowing what the type of e is, but how can I call a subclass method when the code thinks it's only of type Entity? Do I need to cast it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Given

> Assuming at this point the code is only calling this when e has the
>   method

You will have to cast the object

```
((SubClass)e).subclassMethod();
```

Obviously, at compile time, this cast will only work if `SubClass` is an actual sub class of `Entity`. At runtime, the cast will only work if `e`'s dynamic type is `SubClass` (or any of its sub types).